# The application has stopped unexpectedly when it loads SQLite database on a real phone

Tags: android, sql

I have an application that uses an SQLite database that is stored in assets folder of my project, it works just fine when I test it on my emulator, but when it comes to a real phone (Galaxy S) it just crashes showing the message : The application ... has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.
I really don't know what can cause such a problem !

Comment: post your code and the logcat content

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. When you post a question, please post the related code, and log cat (or any error log) so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

IF your code is running in emulator and its not running on device then mostly you should be having old database in your phone and the data base is not upgraded, so the new table or field which you are trying may cause the app crash.
We can check by deleting the app or clear data and run your app. Still there is app crash. we need to check the logs....

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried to install my application on another terminal and it worked fine, must've been some kind of old data attached to the app that caused this crash